# dynamic image sizes for uploaded images in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing

in rails, paperclip has a fixed (model-based) definition of image-sizes.

```
has_attached_file :data,
 :styles => { :large => "800x600>", :icon => "50x50#" }, 
 :path => ":rails_root/public/images/files/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
 :url => "/images/files/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
 :convert_options => { :all  => "-colorspace RGB" }, 
 :whiny_thumbnails => true
```

but this example sets the image-dimensions to 2 types (large, icon) in 2 fixed sizes. this is nice for the most issues but not if you like to show a uploaded picture in a different size e.g. 640x480 …

is there a way to have images scaled on the fly - in rails3 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at something like [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/) to process your images instead of Paperclip. It puts the sizing in the view instead of the model and utilizes some caching mechanisms to help with performance.

Comment: that looks realy nice - i've read the docs so far and i will try this. you said „somethink like …” - do you know more of this kind? to have the image-sizes defined by the view is the way i like to use it, and a caching mechanism is quite natural …

Comment: There are a couple of other that do similar, but Dragonfly looks the most robust. Here is the original blog post I found on its usage and also mentions some others: http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/1/2/dragonfly

Answer (score 0):

Scale images on the fly could kill your server ;)

If you only want to show picture, maybe you could use width and/or height attributes of html image tag?

Comment: that delivers the the whole data and scales the images in the browser, this is not fast or a solution for small bandwith visitor - this is not acceptable …

Comment: then take a look at reprocess! method in paperclip, you can call it on individual object, now you need to figure out how to add new style dynamically ;)

Comment: this is the reason why i wrote this question - i did not find a clou to add new style dynamically - i seems to be impossible …